# Selecting values out of XML with SQL Server 2008 with namespaces

Tags: sql, xml, xml-namespaces

My XML looks like

```
<p:initiateTest xmlns:S52="https://collaborate.com/svn/edm/tdp/CharacteristicEnumerations" 
     xmlns:p="http://collaborate.com/svn/capabilities/tdp/ManageNetworkAndServiceDiagnosticsV4/" 
     xmlns:p1="http://wsi.nat.com/2005/06/StandardHeader/" 
     xmlns:p2="https://collaborate.com/svn/edm/tdp/Test" 
     xmlns:p3="https://collaborate.com/svn/edm/tdp/Parties" 
     xmlns:p4="https://collaborate.com/svn/edm/tdp/MORT" >
   <p1:standardHeader>
      <p1:stateCode>OK</p1:stateCode>
   </p1:standardHeader>
</p:initiateTest>
```

And when I run the TSQL below it completes but does not return the statecode value

```
Declare @mxml XML 

Select @mxml = xmlString
From CT_GTCS_Temp_XML
Where ID = 1

;WITH XMLNAMESPACES(  'p' AS p, 'p1' as p1, 'p2' AS p2)

select feed.xx.value('.','VARCHAR(MAX)') as statecode
from @mxml.nodes('//p:initiateTest/p1:standardHeader/p1:stateCode') feed(xx)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to define the **namespaces** - not the prefixes! - in your `WITH XMLNAMESPACES` statement.

Try this:

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES
   ('http://collaborate.com/svn/capabilities/tdp/ManageNetworkAndServiceDiagnosticsV4/' AS p, 
    'http://wsi.nat.com/2005/06/StandardHeader/' as p1)
select 
    feed.xx.value('.','VARCHAR(MAX)') as statecode
from 
    @mxml.nodes('/p:initiateTest/p1:standardHeader/p1:stateCode') feed(xx)
```