# Select in XML with namespace returning null

Tags: sql-server, xml

I receive an XML file from a web service and, and sometimes this XML comes with a namespace, and sometimes it doesn't.

When I have the XML contained in the @myDoc variable, the select returns null. But, if I remove the "xmlns" part, the select returns the value normally.

What am I doing wrong?

```
DECLARE @myDoc xml
DECLARE @CSTAT VARCHAR(MAX);
SET @myDoc = '<infProt Id="ID311140002329206" xmlns="some_namespace">
    <cStat>100</cStat>
</infProt>'
SET @CSTAT =  @myDoc.value('(/infProt/cStat)[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)' )
SELECT @CSTAT
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Selecting values out of XML with SQL Server 2008 with namespaces](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17697816/selecting-values-out-of-xml-with-sql-server-2008-with-namespaces)

Comment: Also see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177400.aspx.

Comment: Patrick, I read the links, but my problem was that, sometimes the namespace came in the XML, and sometimes didn't. When I used the wildcards proposeds by Mikael, it worked!

Comment: @abeppler then it is not an issue of your code but a web service's one... you can work around this broken behaviour of the web service learning to handle namespaces inside your sql code but the correct solution is to fix the web service.

Comment: I agree with you @Paolo, but I just use the web service, I'm not the developer of it... :(

Comment: You're capable of _complaining_ about the service, aren't you? Maybe the developers would appreciate knowing they have a bug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify the name space using `WITH XMLNAMESPACES`, and attribute an alias to the namespace (I've used `x` here). Note that you'll also need to switch the `SET` to a `SELECT` to use this:

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('some_namespace' as x)
SELECT @CSTAT =  @myDoc.value('(/x:infProt/x:cStat)[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)' );
```

[SqlFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/23468)

**Edit, Re : Dynamic with / without namespaces**

You can use the namespace agnostic function `local-name()` to bypass namespaces:

```
SELECT @CSTAT =  @myDoc.value(
      '(/*[local-name()="infProt"]/*[local-name()="cStat"])[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)');
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/23468)

The mandatory caveat when using `local-name()` is that this will obviously detect an element in any namespace with the same name in the path, unless you also use `namespace-uri`.

Comment: Thanks Stuart, and when I had a xml without the namespace? Because I will have the two possibilities. Can I do it dinamically?

Comment: Updated, with fiddle.

Comment: Or a wildcard. `@myDoc.value('(/*:infProt/*:cStat)[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)' )`

Comment: Thanks Mikael! It's exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

For value() method declare namespace inside select text

```
DECLARE @myDoc xml
DECLARE @CSTAT VARCHAR(MAX);
SET @myDoc = '<infProt Id="ID311140002329206" xmlns="some_namespace">
    <cStat>100</cStat>
</infProt>'
select  @CSTAT =  @myDoc.value('declare namespace x="some_namespace"; ( /x:infProt/x:cStat)[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)' )
select @CSTAT
```