# Getting blank result when parsing xml in MS SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server, xml-parsing

I am trying to parse XML data stored in a SQL server table. I have tried using the following code (adjusted to remove personal information and to show the setup) but it is returning a blank. Is there some way to do this to get my result?  The expected result should be

> Your claim has been rejected on 2022/10/22. Your claim has been
> rejected. Reason: This is an inactive scheme. Please contact the
> Client Service Centre on 123456789 or at email@mail.com for
> assistance.

```
declare @tempxml as table (xmlstr varchar(max));
insert into @tempxml
values (replace('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<hb:MedicalAidMessage xmlns:hb="address.co.za/messaging"
                      Version="6.0.0">
    <Claim>
        <Details>
            <Responses>
                <Response Type="Error">
                    <Code>6</Code>
                    <Desc>Your claim has been rejected on 2022/10/22. Your claim has been rejected. Reason: This is an inactive scheme. Please contact the Client Service Centre on 123456789 or at email@mail.com for assistance.</Desc>
                </Response>
            </Responses>
        </Details>
    </Claim>
</hb:MedicalAidMessage> ',':',''))

declare @XMLData xml
set @XMLData = (select * from @tempxml)

select [Reason] = n.value('Desc[1]', 'nvarchar(2000)')
  from @XMLData.nodes('/hbMedicalAidMessage/Claim/Details/Reponses/Response') as a(n)
```

Thanks

Comment: You haven't defined your namespaces. The first node isn't `hbMedicalAidMessage`, it's `MedicalAidMessage` in the namespace `hb`.

Comment: Hmm, the example I copied this from did not define a namespace and seemed to work. how do I define a namespace?

Comment: [WITH XMLNAMESPACES](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/with-xmlnamespaces?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: Not following how that should look. What would be an example of that declaration?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Select in XML with namespace returning null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27546844/select-in-xml-with-namespace-returning-null)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sql query xml values returning NULL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44156552/sql-query-xml-values-returning-null)

Comment: Tried adding WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://www.webserviceX.NET/'), just before the select  It made no difference, still returned nothing

Comment: `DEFAULT` isn't what you want here, your other nodes are using that namespace, only `MedicalAidMessage` is. The 2 duplicate suggestions above demonstrate how to define the named namespace and use it in your `nodes`/`value` methods.

Comment: What is the motivation for removing the `:` characters from the XML?

Comment: Also, `Reponses` in the XQuery is not the same as `Responses` in the XML.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning it gives an error, Msg 2229, Level 16, State 1, Line 23
XQuery [nodes()]: The name "hb" does not denote a namespace.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning THANK YOU! That was the problem, didn't see my spelling error. Wh not give it as an answer so i can accept it?\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following queries which demonstrate two ways to access the namespace-referenced elements correctly:

```sql
select [Reason] = Response.value('(Desc/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(2000)')
from @XMLData.nodes('
  declare namespace foo = "address.co.za/messaging";
  /foo:MedicalAidMessage/Claim/Details/Responses/Response') as a(Response);
```

```sql
with xmlnamespaces('address.co.za/messaging' as foo)
select [Reason] = Response.value('(Desc/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(2000)')
from @XMLData.nodes('/foo:MedicalAidMessage/Claim/Details/Responses/Response') as a(Response);
```

Note that the namespace prefix `foo` in the queries does not match the `hb` prefix in the original XML. It's not the prefixes that need to match the XML but the namespaces they reference which, in all cases, is `address.co.za/messaging`.